# how to count proper array element which contain value

Tags: php

I have an array which contain value string value and null value.. I want to count all element who assigned string value.

```
     $items = array('name'=>'abc','contact'=>'0177....','address'=>'','country'='')
     expected result:
     $items = array('name'=>'abc','contact'=>'0177....')
     and count new array element $items
```

I want to convert actual array
and count element of newly created array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to simply use `array_filter` and store it within some variable like as

```
$items = array('name'=>'abc','contact'=>'0177','address'=>'','country'=>'');
$filtered_arr = array_filter($items);
echo count($filtered_arr);
print_r($filtered_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) here.

```
echo count(array_filter($items));
```

Comment: Thanks to all,
it's simple but i wouldn't know

Comment: Please vote the answer up and accept it in case it solves your purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
 $result = array();
 $items = array('name'=>'abc','contact'=>'0177....','address'=>'','country'=>'');
 foreach($items as $key => $item)
 {
    if($item != '')
       array_push($result, $item);
 }
 echo "Count ".count($result);
?>
```

OR

```
$items = array('name'=>'abc','contact'=>'0177','address'=>'','country'=>'');
$result = array_filter($items);
echo "Count".count($result);
```